# convert datetime to end-user time zone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

We all know that server time format is UTC, but end-user may access from different time zones. How we could know that end-user's time zone and convert to them in their local time zone.

Comment: Is yours a general question or it's related to asp.net ?

Comment: _"We all know that server time format is UTC"_ - it isn't. Show the code where you output the date.

Comment: @FabrizioAccatino asp.net

Comment: @CodeCaster say for ex when you insert a row we use getdate() to stamp the time... and that is in UTC by default and now i need to display it in end-user's time zone..

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to determine the timezone of the user. You should get the (UTC) offset (in minutes) of the client:

`var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`

And then do the corresponding addition or subtraction to the time you get from the server, to get the end users local time.